# Error with rotation in Google Now Launcher

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, home-screen, google-now, wallpaper, samsung-nexus-10

I have a Google Nexus 10, 16GB, with Android KitKat, v4.4.2. Yesterday I installed Google Now Launcher and when the launcher is rotated the wallpaper does not fit the screen properly in portrait mode.

Here's the home screen when on landscape:

[image: Landscape]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

And here's the home screen when on portrait mode:

[image: Portrait]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

I have tried setting the wallpaper while in portrait, but it still looks the same.
What could be the problem with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to android trying to keep same aspect ratio of wallpaper when  your device is switching between portrait and landscape modes. What is the size of the wallpaper? For it to fit perfectly, it must be 3966x2560.